# Error after chown to be able to install ruby gems

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems

I´m having a problem with the mac terminal. After running chown command, i restarted the terminal and i got this error:

Last login: Mon Aug 12 00:15:55 on ttys000
login(862,0x7fff7d001180) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe09ac002a0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]

I got the same error earlier today and i then had to re-install osx to get it to work. Is there a reason for this? is there a way for me to make the terminal work again without having to re-install?

Comment: We need a lot more information than "After running chown command". What did you type *exactly*? Why, after reinstalling Mac OS X did you run `chown` anything? And why is this related to Ruby? This is very off-topic for Stack Overflow and would be better on http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: it´s related to ruby because to install ruby gems i have to chown usr/bin and that is whats giving the error?

Comment: No, you do NOT have to chown /usr/bin. That just shows you're unprepared to administer a system if you think that. Instead, install RVM or rbenv (which I recommend). Do *NOT* change anything that is not in your own user space unless you understand the implications, and why you should do it. Who told you that you need to `chown` /usr/bin? At the worst you should use `sudo`, but even then I'd strongly recommend you avoid using `sudo` for anything until you *really* understand what it does and why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Without having to re-install: Use Disk Utility.app and select the boot disk in the left hand list of disks.Click Repair Disk Permissions.